# Aligning ViewPager and TextView Vertically

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout, android-viewpager, vertical-alignment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Layout-Normal-Portrait -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumb_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/mypager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_above="@id/sum_layout"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/sum_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/thumb_layout" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:text="@string/lorem__ipsum"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As soon as I run the program, it shows a error in the editor saying "**error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/sum_layout').**" which is at line 22 in this code.

Can any one tell, what is wrong?

Comment: you found Error: No resource found because it didnt get the id of layout to whom you want to set above of it.first add layout having id @+id/sum_layout, than add the viewpager above the layout having id @+id/sum_layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder why you are making it so complex.

Anyways here is corrected snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Layout-Normal-Portrait -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" > <---No need to specify android:orientation

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/mypager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />  <---Place your text String here 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `@+id/sum_layout`

and clean Project and run again!

Comment: It works fine but a new problem arises. There used to be a some text text in my TextView. Now its showing none.

Comment: Now if I set the layout_height attribute of the ViewPager to fill_parent it takes up the whole screen. But I want it to adjust its height by (TotalScreenHeight - TextViewHeight) manner. Do I need to do this dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you declare sum_layout id AFTER its first reference.
The best solution is to declare it in the /res/values/ids.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources> 
     <item type="id" name="sum_layout" />
</resources>
```

And then reference it in all your layouts without the + keyword

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_above="@id/sum_layout"
    />
```

And

```
 <RelativeLayout android:id="@id/sum_layout" />
```

Comment: Now if I set the layout_height attribute of the ViewPager to fill_parent it takes up the whole screen. But I want it to adjust its height by (TotalScreenHeight - TextViewHeight) manner. Do I need to do this dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"


android:layout_width="fill_parent"


android:layout_height="fill_parent"

android:background="@color/white"

android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

    android:id="@+id/mypager"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="300dp"

    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:padding="6dp"

    android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

Comment: Now if I set the layout_height attribute of the ViewPager to fill_parent it takes up the whole screen. But I want it to adjust its height by (TotalScreenHeight - TextViewHeight) manner. Do I need to do this dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using relative layout, you are relating the controls with each other.when you add any control you add next control with respect to the control defined before.Likewise here you have defined view pager layout which is under layout having id @+id/sum_layout. but you have defined layout @+id/sum_layout under view pager.so it doesn't get id @+id/sum_layout,so how it will set view pager under the text view.first of all add the view and then add to its under/above.Here is your mistake:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/mypager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp">    
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:text="@string/lorem__ipsum"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mypager"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Set the layout according to this wherever you have to keep to its below or above.
hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the solution.
But it was a experimental one. I was trying to use it by setting the layout_height property of the ViewPager to "fill_parent". While doing this it was taking up the whole screen. Now it fine. Thanks to eveyone.

Comment: It's my pleasure.Always keep in mind what you are going to do.you are relating to the one which is not declared how android will come to know to whom to refer?? You are relating that keep textview below viewpager but first of all declare viewpager..thats why it was giving error resource not found.